# Change file format from .xls to .csv in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

**EDIT:**
I have now encountered an additional error. regardless of file format -4143 or 6... I have had the date format not return as dd/mm/yyyy.
Where the day is only a single digit, it returns d/mm/yyyy.
Is there a way to also fix this*

---

I have attempted to split a master .csv file into separate files with the header in each new file and a max 500 rows of data. When I have done this, my original file is a .csv, but the output files are all .xls.

Requirements:

1. Original file = .xlsx.
2. All output files must have the same headers.
3. All output files must have a max of 500 rows of data.
4. All output files must be .csv format.
5. All output files must save with a new concurrent file name e.g. file-1, file-2.

I run this code through the Developer Tab in excel and as it is a csv file, I am using the active spreadsheet.

I believe the error is to do with the file format being -4143, but when I have changed this, the code breaks so I am not sure how to proceed.

```
Sub alm()
 
Dim ACS As Range, Z As Long, New_WB As Workbook, _
Total_Columns As Long, Start_Row As Long, Stop_Row As Long, Copied_Range As Range
 
Dim Headers() As Variant
 
Set ACS = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 
With ACS
 
    Headers = .Rows(1).Value
    Total_Columns = .Columns.Count
     
End With
 
Start_Row = 2
 
Do While Stop_Row <= ACS.Rows.Count
     
    Z = Z + 1
     
    If Z > 1 Then Start_Row = Stop_Row + 1
     
    Stop_Row = Start_Row + 499
     
    With ACS.Rows
        If Stop_Row > .Count Then Stop_Row = .Count
    End With
     
    With ACS
        Set Copied_Range = .Range(.Cells(Start_Row, 1), .Cells(Stop_Row, Total_Columns))
    End With
     
    Set New_WB = Workbooks.Add
     
    With New_WB
     
        With .Worksheets(1)
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, Total_Columns) = Headers
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Copied_Range.Rows.Count, Total_Columns) = Copied_Range.Value
        End With
         
       .SaveAs ACS.Parent.Parent.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "file-" & Z & ".csv", FileFormat:=-4143
       .Close
        
    End With
     
    If Stop_Row = ACS.Rows.Count Then Exit Do
     
Loop
 
End Sub
```

When I ran this code and all other requirements worked, however the separated files were saved as .xml, not .csv.

[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZZUD.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. This change worked. However I have encountered another issue I didn't predict. When I save out the CSV's the date recorded changes so the original date format was dd/mm/yyyy, but a single date e.g. 9th shows as d/mm/yyyy.

I thought this might be a limitation of csv's, but tried the code again for the original code above and it still changed the date to d/mm/yyyy. Is there a way around this so the returned result regardless of method will return dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 2):

you are using `FileFormat:=-4143` which is xlWorkbookNormal. So it is saving in excel format with .csv extension. Use 6 (xlCSV), instead.

For making sure to write the dates in the format you want, format the column in that way, before saving as CSV, as in:

.columns(X).numberformat="dd/mm/yyyy", where X is the column number for your dates.

Comment: Thank you so much. This change worked. However I have encountered another issue I didn't predict. When I save out the CSV's the date recorded changes so the original date format was dd/mm/yyyy, but a single date e.g. 9th shows as d/mm/yyyy.

I thought this might be a limitation of csv's, but tried the code again for the original code above and it still changed the date to d/mm/yyyy. Is there a way around this so the returned result regardless of method will return dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: @Alana, did the date formatting work for you?